# MATLAB GUI set default values

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am working on a GUIDE in Matlab and I have to constantly change a couple of Edit Text values.

I have realized that if I change the String value of an Edit Text from the property inspector in the .fig file it sticks there when I run the code even if I close Matlab and reopen it, so I suppose that it is stored somewhere. I would like to know if there is a way of changing those 'default' values while running the gui.

I want to add a pushbutton to set the displayed data as default, so it is kept for the next time I run the code.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I believe that someone already ran into your same problem, and found a solution to it in this [MATLAB forum post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/233909-matlab-set-default-values-for-gui-edit-text-and-use-them-in-push-button-callback). I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a more elegant way, but you can do the following as a workaround:

Once the button is clicked

- Create a file
- Write new default values instead of older ones

At the start of GUI

- Open the file
- Get the default values
- Set the default values on GUI